# Where can I find a good amount of sample elastic search data for practice?

Tags: elasticsearch

Hello ElasticSearchers,

I want to do some practice on sample data set. Can anyone please point me to some freely available data set for practice.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I'd suggest contributing as if it were a meta-question and provide an answer since IMO OP is asking for data discovery help, which is allowed yet.

Answer (score 1):

The Global Terrorism Database (GTD) is an open-source database including information on terrorist events around the world from 1970 through 2016 (with annual updates planned for the future). https://www.start.umd.edu/gtd/

The Armed Conflict Location and Event Data Project (ACLED) is a project that collates data on political violence in developing states, from 1997 to the present. https://www.acleddata.com/data/

2 datasets for the same category, covering the same topic and timeline, geo-tagged, a good example for collect, explore and transform, ideal to make a search engine, aggregator, and deduplication exercises.